# Unity - Collision detection issue with CharacterController

Tags: unity, c#

I am making an isometric game (3d scene, using 2d sprites). Currently I am trying to add collision to the enviroment to prevent the player from walking through everything. However no matter what I do the player seems to simply ignore the and walks through the object. Below are some combination I have tried and the results I got. For this instance I am looking at the windmill object

NOTE: Player has a character controller , no rigidbody.

**Scenario 1:**

- Windmill has Rigibody
- IsKinematic false
- No rotation & Position constraints
- Boxcollider isTrigger == false

result: On touching object it start flying around. So collision is there.

**Scenario 2:**

- Windmill has Rigibody
- IsKinematic false
- has rotation & Position constraints (all axis)
- Boxcollider isTrigger == false

result: I can walk through the object and somehow the collision is gone. the reason for constraints is so that the object wont move. (its a windmill)

**Scenario 3:**

- Windmill has Rigibody

  - IsKinematic false
  - both with and without rotation & Position constraints (all axis)
  - Boxcollider isTrigger == true

result: Debug.Log shows that there is collision

Now what I would like to achieve is that the windmill can't be moved yet also can't be moved through.I am willing to programm collision if needed, but i rather do it with the unity provided tools. Any idea what I am overlooking?

EDIT 1:

Since it was asked how I moved the player, I use the [Fingers asset](https://www.assetstore.unity3d.com/en/#!/content/41076). We make use of the joystick to move the player around. Below is our JoystickExecuted method depicting what exactly I do.

```
 private void JoystickExecuted(FingersJoystickScript script, Vector2 amount)
{
    if (amount.x > 0 && !_facingRight)
    {
        FlipXAxis();
    }
    else if (amount.x < 0 && _facingRight)
    {
        if (amount.x > 0 && !_facingRight)
        {
            FlipXAxis();
        }
        else if (amount.x < 0 && _facingRight)
        {
            FlipXAxis();
        }
    }
    var pos = transform.position;
    pos.x += amount.x * 8 * Time.deltaTime;
    pos.z += amount.y * 8 * Time.deltaTime;
    transform.position = pos;
    _anim.SetBool("isWalking", true);

    if (amount == Vector2.zero)
    {
        _anim.SetBool("isWalking", false);
    }
}
```

Comment: Why has the player no Rigidbody?

Comment: This has been tested but also did't work. It will later however. As rigibody affects game performance a lot

Comment: How are you moving the PlayerController?

Comment: @EdMarty it is a mobile game, we are using fingers for that. https://www.assetstore.unity3d.com/en/#!/content/41076 I added the method responsible for the joystickmovement

Comment: Are you using `CharacterController.Move` or `CharacterController.SimpleMove`? It looks like you're just setting the transform.position, which is not how `CharacterController` works.

Comment: I am using transform.position, whould using one of those work.

Comment: When i change it to a boxcollider on the player there is not collision registered

Comment: You should not set transform.position. Instead use `CharacterController.Move` and this should correct strange jittering issues. Also, use `OnControllerColliderHit` to listen for collisions.